# I need report in Separate page

Tags: crystal-reports

Can you please assist me the solution on how to get the record details in separate page by date wise. Currently, I am getting all records together in crystal report 9.2.

I tried a formula like below

```
 IF Remainder (Record Number, 8) = 0 THEN 

    TRUE 

ELSE

    FALSE
```

But in my records details, each record has different columns.

Comment: Are you using the formula for "new break before" in "section expert"?

Comment: Yes..I used this formula "New break before " & after page too in "section export" but still i'm facing same problem. Here I have two details section like a & b and every report(part no) have different number of records like 22,20,15 etc.

Comment: Can anyone pls help...

Comment: May you post screenshots of your design and formula?

Comment: There is no formula I used here is code. Case UCase("Internal_Inspection_Standard.RPT")  REP_NAME = path & "Internal_Inspection_Standard.RPT"  Set REP = crapp.OpenReport(REP_NAME)   REP_PARA(0).pno = 1   REP_PARA(0).DNAME = "Select Part No Number"
   REP_PARA(0).PNAME = ""   REP_PARA(0).CTYPE = "="   REP_PARA(0).VTYPE = "S"   REP_PARA(0).HQRY = "SELECT DISTINCT p_code,b.PART_NAME,REVISENO FROM IIS_TRA_MSRMT_" & YEARID & " A LEFT JOIN BOM_MAS_BOM_REP_" & YEARID & " B ON A.p_code = B.ITEM_CODE"   REP_PARA(0).Chk_ALL = False. I unable to attach screenshot option here unable to attach screenshot.

Comment: Here is screenshot https://imgur.com/znVgwhL and https://imgur.com/a/CEWrLSS